# Javascript var assignment

Tags: javascript, variables, evaluation, comma-operator

Is this correct? Does the b assignment belongs to already declared b?

```
var a, b;
//...later
a = 3, b = a * 4;
```

Or it needs to be like this?

```
var a, b;
//...later
a = 3; 
b = a * 4;
```

Comment: Both works. You don't need to follow the same convention when you declared the variables when you use them.

Comment: It works fine the first way. You could have just as easily tested it for yourself.

Comment: it's adviable to not use the comma operator on expressions like that, as it's less-readable to most coders than distinct "sections" using semi-colons. it's one of the reasons uglify'd code is hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The **comma operator** evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So, `b = a * 4` will be evaluated after `a = 3` and will result in 12.

The difference between the 2 versions is that the latter consists of an additional statement. If you type these statements one after another in a REPL,  you'll see the `a = 3` statement evaluated as 3, which won't happen in the former version.